# В атрибуте HTML value отображается только 1 слово из строки

Tags: php, html

Суть проблемы в том, что в атрибуте тега input value отображается только часть строки, которую я пытаюсь туда записать. собственно в чем может быть проблема?

Этот код(часть его) предназначен для редактирования данных из sql таблицы через html форму.

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");
//echo isset($arraySum[$i]['id']);

//var_dump($_POST['changeTitle']);

if(isset($_POST['changeTitle'])) {
$query = 'SELECT title, article, datepubl FROM news WHERE     
id="'.$_POST['changeTitle'].'"';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Wrong $query');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
var_dump($row['title']);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<form>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="title">Заголовок</label>
<input type="text" name="title" value=<?php echo $row['title'];?>><br>
<label for="acticle">Текст</label>
<input type="text" name="article" value=<?php echo $row['article'];?>><br>
<label for="date">Дата</label>
<input type="date" name="date" value=<?php echo  $row['datepubl'];?>>
<input type="submit" name="redact" value="Подтвердить изменения">
</form>
</html>
```

[image: Результат исполнения кода]

Результат исполнения кода.
Суть в том, что вместо записи в строку всей строки 'new test' в поле отображается только 1 слово 'new'.
Почему это происходит?Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, все атрибуты надо обрамлять **кавычками**.
Во-вторых, любой вывод в HTML нужно всегда кодировать соответствующим образом.

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($row['title'])?>">
```

Comment: Не поверите, только что сам это наугад сделал))но спасибо